# Why does my Mail App for Office show in Outlook online but not in my installed Outlook Client?

Tags: office365, office365-apps

I have developed a mail app for office.

It is showing in my Office 365 Outlook in my browser but not in my installed client.

[image: On the web]

But in my installed client it looks like this. Ie the app is not showing:

[image: In the client]

I have looked at managing apps etc but can't find any settings to force it to show in my installed client.

Any ideas?

Here is my manifest:

[image: Manfest]

Please note, this is not a real app but more of a "trying things out" app.

ok so here is my version of Office:
[image]

And here is my updated manifest file as @andrews requested I remove the regex rules to simplify trouble shooting:

[image]

I un-installed the app, restarted everything and I still cant see it in my Outlook desktop client.

thanks
Russ

Comment: thanks JWW. I am a developer and I developed this as a programmer so I am thinking that other developers may have had the same issue.

Comment: My bad. I did not parse the question properly.

Comment: Can you please provide us with the manifest you're using for the app? Also, restarting Outlook may be necessary to refresh the list of apps available.

Comment: Thanks @MrPiao. I have rerstarted Outlook numerous times. I have also supplied my manifest for you to look at. Let me know if you see anything that is not right. thanks Russ

Comment: My coworker @AndrewS is trying to help debug in the comment section of his answer below. You may have to click "expand" to see it, so please take a look.

Comment: Thanks @MrPiao. Yes, I think he is having some issues with being blocked from commenting. Ill wait a while to see what happens. My email is russell.mccloy@googlemail.com if he cant get Stack to work.

Comment: No, what I meant is he can still comment on his answer below, so you can communicate there. Just scroll down and click on "show # more comments" in his answer below.

Comment: All, I have the beginning of a comment in my email account: : Hey @RuSs - as I suspected, your Outlook build # is not SP1. The manifest version you're usin..... but it is not showing on this page even when I click, show all comments. If you recognise this as the beginning of your comment, can you please re-post as I think it will answer the question and I will mark it as answered for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your manifest is version 1.1, but your Outlook build is not 2013 SP1. Outlook 2013 SP1 builds are 15.0.4569 and higher. Please update your Outlook client, and then the app will appear!

Comment: Thanks @AndrewS,
I just upgraded to the latest Outlook Client and all works fine now. Appreciate you help.